# Getting error while restarting the MarkLogic service on Linux

Tags: marklogic

While starting the Marklogic service on Linux getting the below error.

```
systemctl status MarkLogic.service
● MarkLogic.service - LSB: MarkLogic Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/MarkLogic; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-12-15 12:30:21 UTC; 1min 58s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 12163 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/MarkLogic start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Starting LSB: MarkLogic Server...
TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid
systemd[1]: MarkLogic.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: MarkLogic Server.
systemd[1]: Unit MarkLogic.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: MarkLogic.service failed.
```

Could you please help me.

**Update:**

On running the `journalctl -xe` command getting the below error.

```
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 22 08:04:39 HOST.ds sudo[5380]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 22 08:04:39 HOST.ds sudo[5380]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 22 08:04:39 HOST.ds MarkLogic[5387]: requires a Java JVM to run on EC2 - Please install a java JVM
Dec 22 08:04:39 HOST.ds systemd[1]: MarkLogic.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 22 08:04:39 HOST.ds systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: MarkLogic Server.
-- Subject: Unit MarkLogic.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit MarkLogic.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Dec 22 08:04:39 HOST.ds systemd[1]: Unit MarkLogic.service entered failed state.
Dec 22 08:04:39 HOST.ds systemd[1]: MarkLogic.service failed.
Dec 22 08:04:39 HOST.ds polkitd[1030]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:5371:240358 (system bus name :1.36, object path /org/freedesktop
```

In the error it's saying that  `requires a Java JVM to run on EC2 - Please install a java JVM` but as far as I know for MarkLogic java is never required.

replaced the hostname with `HOST.ds`.

Comment: Is there anything written to the ErrorLog.txt? What about /var/log/messages? If so, can you post that as well?

Comment: Is this a new installation, or was it working before?

Comment: It's a new installation

Comment: A blind guess would be that one or more of the ports are already in use, but you should be able see some clues in either the MarkLogic or system logs.

Comment: updated the question with more logs, please have a look.(why java is required for MarkLogic)?

Comment: Java was used for Hadoop support, which has since been deprecated. If you have Java installed, ensure that you have JAVA_HOME defined as a system variable, or add as an entry in /etc/marklogic.conf https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/GettingStarted#id_64949 You could also disable the Java checks by adding `export MARKLOGIC_DISABLE_JVM=1` to /etc/marklogic.conf